# KafkStreams: Discard message during a window

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Need to discard duplicate message within a time window. Message are coming in continuously. Bellow is the part of the code.

```
 kStream.groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(15)))
             .reduce((k,m) -> m)
             .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
             .toStream()
             .foreach((k, v) -> doSomeProcess(k,v));
```

What I am doing wrong here. I am not seeing any call to the method doSomeProcess. Messages are coming in.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that "This feature requires adding a "grace period" parameter for windows" From https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-328%3A+Ability+to+suppress+updates+for+KTables
....
.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(15)).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(5)) )
....

This fixed the issue.